# Oracle SQL - simulate long running query without dbms_lock.sleep(sec)

Tags: sql, oracle, timeout, simulation

**Question**

Is there some way in Oracle SQL to simulate long running query ?

**Why?**

I want to test jdbc timeouts on Tomcat server from Java.
Ideally I want some view that calls proc/function which would be sleep for defined time.

**Problem**

I have no access to use dbms_lock procedure, so I have to use something else.

Answer (score 3):

So, i have a solution for this.

**Solution**

I have created VIEW in the database, which calls my func.

*View:*

```
create or replace VIEW TEST_VIEW (ID) as SELECT TEST_PROC() as ID from dual;
```

*Func:*

```
create or replace function TEST_PROC return number is
IS
start_time DATE := sysdate;
end_time DATE;
curr_time: DATE;
id number :=0;
begin
end_time := start_time + interval '30' minute; // here you may define time as you need.
loop id := id + 1;
curr_time := sysdate;
exit when curr_time > end_time;
end loop;
return id;
end TEST_PROC
```

Maybe that's would be helpful for someone.

BR.

Comment: Perfect ! A little remark : double IS keyword in the function creation.